# MSXML client side XSLT does not send accept-language header

Tags: http, xslt, msxml

When using client side XSLT in IE9 I noticed that IE sends different headers for requests that fetch the XSL and subsequent requests triggered via the `document()` method, than for requesting the original XML file. In particular the `accept-language` header is missing completely.

The bootstrap XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transform.xsl"?>
<root/>
```

and the XSLT like this

```
...
<body>
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('section.xml')"/>
</body>
...
```

What I notice is that both the XSLT as well as the `section.xml` file are loaded with an HTTP request without an accept language header. 
The request headers to fetch the XML file look like this:

```
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,de-DE;q=0.5
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

whereas the other resources are loaded with

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Is is a feature or a bug? Other browsers such as FF or Chrome send identical headers.

A working example can be found on [my test server](http://carsten-leue.de/test/xslt/index.xml)

This effect causes problems in a real life project, because the XML files are generated dynamically and contain end-user facing content that is negotiated based on the `accept-language` header. This fails because no header is sent by the transformer.

Any insight or suggestions for workarounds are welcome!
Thanks!
Carsten

Comment: This is just a random guess (because I honestly have no idea what this is supposed to do), but does anything change when you set the `ServerHTTPRequest` property to `true`?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms766434(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I am actually relying on the browser to execute the transform automatically by assiging the XSL to the XML document. So I don't have a hook to manipulate scripting objects.

Answer (score 0):

I vote for "bug" since it seems more logical to repeat the accept-language header for the dependent requests (not sure if that would be specified anywhere). Could you carry the language preference information as a query parameter for the request fetching the XSL?